# New-TfsChangeset with multiple items

Tags: powershell, tfs-power-tools

I am just learning to use the powerscript cmdlets for PowerTools for TFS (2012), and have come across the command `New-TfsChangeset`, which I understand can be used as follows: `New-TfsChangeset -Item "C:\fake\path" -Comment "checking in a folder" -Verbose`

My question is, how could you check in multiple items in the same changeset this way? I assume -Recurse will work for all sub-folders? but what if they're not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C:\fake\path*.xml. Or any list (Get-Content list.txt | where {...}).